# WCF: Notify Clent Server Connction in both sides (Service Self Hosted as console application)

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service, self hosted on a console application. I can successfully connect and communicate.

I need to push some data to Client from server when a connection is established. How could I understand that a client has been connected and vice-versa (client knows when server connection established).

//Create a URI to serve as the base address
            Uri httpUrl = new Uri("http://localhost:8090/TAOInventoryService/InventoryManager");

```
        //Create ServiceHost
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(TAOInventoryService.InventoryManager), httpUrl);

        //Add a service endpoint
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(TAOInventoryService.IInventoryManager ), new WSHttpBinding(), "");

        //Enable metadata exchange
        ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

        //Start the Service
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Service is host at " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Host is running... Press  key to stop");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

I might not fully understand your issue. In my opinion. It’s a bit like online and offline notifications. When the server is online, it can actively push an announcement message to the client.
Here is an example I ever wrote, wish it is useful to you.
**Server.**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:21011");
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None;
            using (ServiceHost sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), uri))
            {
                sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), binding, "");
                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb;
                smb = sh.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
                if (smb == null)
                {
                    smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior()
                    {
                        HttpGetEnabled = true
                    };
                    sh.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
                }
                ServiceDiscoveryBehavior sdb = new ServiceDiscoveryBehavior();
                sdb.AnnouncementEndpoints.Add(new UdpAnnouncementEndpoint());
                sh.Description.Behaviors.Add(sdb);
                sh.AddServiceEndpoint(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
                Binding mexbinding = MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding();
                sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), mexbinding, "mex");
                sh.Opened += delegate
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Service is ready");                    
                };
                sh.Closed += delegate
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Service is clsoed");                    
                };
                sh.Open();
                Console.ReadLine();
                //pause
                sh.Close();
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        Int32 Add(Int32 Num1, Int32 Num2);

    }
    [ServiceBehavior]
    public class MyService : IService
    {
        public int Add(int Num1, int Num2)
        {
            return Num1 + Num2;
        }
    }
```

**Client.**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.Title = "Start client first";

            AnnouncementService annsvc = new AnnouncementService();
            annsvc.OnlineAnnouncementReceived += OnlineRec;
            annsvc.OfflineAnnouncementReceived += OfflineRec;
            using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(annsvc))
            {
                host.AddServiceEndpoint(new UdpAnnouncementEndpoint());
                host.Open();
                Console.Read();
            }
        }

        private static void OfflineRec(object sender, AnnouncementEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\nService is offline, service address：{e.EndpointDiscoveryMetadata.Address.Uri}");
        }

        private static void OnlineRec(object sender, AnnouncementEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\nService is online, service address：{e.EndpointDiscoveryMetadata.Address.Uri}");
        }
```

Result.
[image]
Official document.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/dd483353(v=vs.100)
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thank yo very much. Let me try to tune it to my scenario.